# How do I upload Cyanagenmod when the only things I have access to are Download mode and ClockworkMod recovery?

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-tab

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 7, the UK version. I managed to mess up in the beginning when trying to install CM and now have it in a state where I can either boot into Download mode or ClockworkMod Recovery.

The [instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_p1) say to use ADB to connect and upload the zip file, but this doesn't seem to work in either of the two modes I can boot into. I can no longer boot into stock Android to copy the file across there either.

How do I upload the CM zip file? Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: It says 'error: device offline'. If I list the devices I get '<serial> offline'. I've tried under both Windows and Linux with the same result.

Comment: I'm using the stock cable. I tried install Kies after I started this debacle and it won't talk to the Tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recovery mode, use this:

```
adb shell mount /sdcard
adb push {filename} /sdcard/{filename}
```

**UPDATE #1:** An alternative suggested by ce4:

> Pull out the SD card, copy all needed files externally, and put it
>   back in

**UPDATE #2:** It seems the user did not install CWM correctly. After fixing this, adb push now works as expected.

Comment: Still says 'error: device offline'. Should I be in download mode or recovery?

Comment: Sorry, you did say recovery mode. I wasn't reading properly.

Comment: Yes, recovery. If that doesn't work. Try with another cable. If that doesn't work, try plugging it at the USB at the back of the PC.

Comment: You can also pull out the SD card, copy all needed files externally and put it back in. Then boot the recovery.

Comment: @ce4 BEST and EASIEST idea ever. I always used to do that. A shame I didn't think of it. LOL.

Comment: @ce4 But chances are he may not have a card reader.

Comment: The storage marked as /sdcard is actually internal. There is an external card and I have uploaded the file to it, but when I browse to it on the Tab, the external storage directory appears empty.

Comment: @Simmo Are you uploading it to the correct path? In my case, the External SD is /storage/extSdCard on my Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: I don't have a reader so I stuck the card in an old phone temporarily. I copied the .zip to the root of the card. On the Tab it's listed as /sdcard/external_sd, but that directory is always empty.

Comment: Wish I had CWM right now... From the CWM, can you post the path you are going to? I can't remember the menus in CWM.

Comment: Menu - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19316597/menu.jpg

Comment: External card, empty listing - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19316597/empty_card.jpg

Comment: I realised I hadn't actually been successful in installing ClockworkMod Recovery. Once I'd managed to do that correctly, I was forward a step and your tip worked. Still isn't working but that's a question for another page.

Comment: @Simmo +1 to your question, and I added your updates to my answer. :)